# Почему не срабатывает псевдоэлемент?

Tags: css

Пытаюсь назначить стиль псевдоэлемента, справа должна граница вырисовываться после каждого элемента li, но стиль не работает

```
.menu .menu_item::after {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 31px;
    mix-blend-mode: soft-light;

}
```

должно вот так быть

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот весь код

```css
* {
    font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
}

header {
    height: 67px;
    background-color: #212121;
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    padding: 26px 70px 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}
.menu .menu_link {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  
}
.menu .menu_item::after {
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 31px;
    mix-blend-mode: soft-light;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Главная</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Со своим автомобилем</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">На автомобиле компании</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Требования</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li class="menu_item"><a href="#" class="menu_link">Оставить заявку</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Свойство `content: ""` напишите в стиль псевдоэлемента, без него они не работают.

И [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) должен смешивать цвет элемента с фоновым, а у вашего элемента цвета нет. Добавьте какой-нибудь фоновой цвет ему.

Ещё строчным элементам нельзя задать ширину, они от контента работают. Нужно их сделать `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Исправил, не работает, сейчас в вопрос исправленный код добавлю

Comment: Отредактировал исправление в вопросе, не работает

Comment: @РусланКамов вы не вставили `display:inline-block` для `.menu .menu_item::after`. Еще для `.menu_link` назначить `display:flex`.

Comment: @Pavel Вы имеете в виду что он цвет текста (например color:black) смешивает с background-color?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что если не задать ничего видимо в псевдо-элемент, то и показываться ничего не будет, нечего смешивать тогда.